# Is it possible to restore table without backup in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, disaster-recovery

Is it possible to do it without ANY backup? I need to reverse one command.

Comment: If you can't rollback that command, you're toast.

Comment: What is the command you issued that you want to reverse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, out of the box. 
What you can do is to inspect "deleted" data using [pageinspect](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/pageinspect.html).